# How delete item from more one lists by using one for loop

Tags: python

I working in employee application. l enter employees _id,employees _name and employees department.l need to delete employee by using one for loop and all information about one employee is deleting just if l enter his name.like this

```
Emp_name=[]
Emp_id=[]
Emp_dep=[]
num=5
for n in emp_name:
 x =input("enter the name of employees")
 emp_name.append(x)
for n in emp_id:
 i =input("enter the name of employees")
 emp_name.append(i)

for n in emp_name:
 d =input("enter the name of employees")
 emp_name.append(d)
delete=input(" enter the of employee tou need to delete")
For n in emp_name:
  if delete==emp_name:
   emp_name.remove(n)
   emp_id.remove(n)
   emp_department.remove(n)
```

This is just delete his name ,l need to delete his id and his department if l just enter his name

Comment: Don't you already use one for loop to delete?

Comment: you variable names has many bad styles, and even errors. please correct all typo first.

Comment: Find the index of the employee name you want to delete, then remove the corresponding item at that index from each list. Alternatively, don't use a list - maintain the data in a dictionary, for example.

Comment: Variable names are case sensitive (e.g. `Emp_name` doesn't match `emp_name`) and `for` doesn't start with an upper case F. Your code is never going to have anything in these lists. Perhaps you should fix all that first before worrying about deleting names.

Comment: @AlainT. I guess, this is mostly meant as pseudo code. As far as I understand his question is not related to code compilation/interpretation, but how to implement some logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have given had lots of error, I'm assuming you wanted to use only 1 for loop for inserting elements.
This will be the code

```
Emp_name = []
Emp_id = []
Emp_dep = []
num = 5
for i in range(num):
    x = input("enter the name of employees")
    Emp_name.append(x)

    i = input("enter the id of employees")
    Emp_id.append(i)

    d = input("enter the department of employees")
    Emp_dep.append(d)
delete = str(input(" Enter the name of employee you need to delete"))
if delete in Emp_name:
    pos = Emp_name.index(delete)
    Emp_name.pop(pos)
    Emp_id.pop(pos)
    Emp_dep.pop(pos)

print(Emp_name)
print(Emp_id)
print(Emp_dep)
```

Comment: Yes, I meant it, and you saw my mistakes. Thank you. I am very grateful and thank you, my friend

Comment: No problem,happy to help.